# Migração de um BD Local para BD MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, visual-studio

Estou elaborando uma pagina WEB ASP.NET com MVC e fiz todas as configurações de modelo, controle e exibição no Visual Studio 2017 e o mesmo criou um BD Local pelo SQL Server LocalDB para armazenar os dados porem existe uma função automatizada que migre a tabela para um BD MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instale o connector MySql no seu projeto. Baixe-o através do site oficial: [Connector MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html)

No seu arquivo **web.config** adicione a propriedade   abaixo do fechamento da propriedade **appSettings**. Esta propriedade define a sua String de conexão no projeto.
Exemplo:
 `<connectionStrings>
<add name="nomedasuastringdeconexao" connectionString="Database=nomedoseudatabase;Data Source=localhost;User Id=seuUsuario;Password=suaSenha;pooling=false" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, funcionou!!!